# Using OpenMP for a MATLAB/MEX function in Windows

Tags: c, multithreading, matlab, openmp, mex

I have a function which I need to use multithreading to speed up the processing time. This function is written in MATLAB/MEX. The general overview of this function is shown in below. `NI`, `NJ`, `NK` are of order `200` and `N` is an integer between `5` to `32`.

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <omp.h>

double spawn_threads(/*my variables in the argument*/)
{
    for( int k = 0; k < NK; k++ )
        for( int j = 0; j < NJ; j++ )
            for( int i = 0; i < NI; i++ )
            {                
                // a small for-loop.
                for( k1 = 0; k1 < N; k1++ )
                    for( j1 = 0; j1 < N; j1++ )
                        for( i1 = 0; i1 < N; i1++ )
                        {
                            // Do some calculation.
                        }

                // another small for-loop.
                for( k1 = 0; k1 < N; k1++ )
                    for( j1 = 0; j1 < N; j1++ )
                        for( i1 = 0; i1 < N; i1++ )
                        {
                            // Do some calculation.
                        }

                call_a_function_using_omp();

                call_a_function_not_using_omp();

                // another for-loop.// another small for-loop.
                for( k1 = 0; k1 < N; k1++ )
                    for( j1 = 0; j1 < N; j1++ )
                        for( i1 = 0; i1 < N; i1++ )
                        {
                            // Do some calculation.
                        }

                // A small linear system of size 3x3.
                call_LAPACK_linear_system_solver();

}

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{
    // Some initialization

    /*Do the parallel computing*/
    spawn_threads(/*my variables for performing the computation*/);

}
```

After searching online, I found out that I may be able to use the following at the beginning of the function `spawn_threads`:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(/*my variables in the argument*/) num_threads(8)
```

I will compile it using `Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional (C)` by:

```
mex my_multithreaded_openmp.c COMPFLAGS="/openmp $COMPFLAGS"
```

If I have three nested loops, each of size `200`, what will happen if I use `#pragma omp parallel for` just before the outer-loop with for example `8` threads?

Is `#pragma omp parallel for` the equivalent version of `parfor` in MATLAB `m`-files?

I would appreciate it to know what methods can be used to make the function `spawn_threads` multithreaded. May I have the community's thought on the this matter?

Comment: I have used OpenMP with MATLAB in Linux, and it seems like you are on the right track. If your algorithm is "embarrasingly parallel", ie one loop iteration doesn't depend on the results of others, then a simple `#pragma omp parallel for` in front of the outer loop will suffice. The only time you need to call `omp` functions is if you need to explicitly control synchronization between threads, but even that can often be done with more `#pragma omp ...`. I think you should play around with OpenMP a bit on its own, and then post here again if you have a specific problem you can't figure out.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need a special care when there is a function inside the outer-loop that uses `omp parallel for`, a function like `call_a_function_using_omp()` in my question?

Comment: Definitely, you never want to nest OpenMP magic. Otherwise, each of your 8 outerloop threads spawn more threads inside `call_a_function_using_omp()`, so you end up with 64 threads, and your CPU will cry since you most likely do not have that many cores.